# powershell delete desktop icon if reg key exist

Tags: powershell, icons, key, registry, desktop

I need to delete a desktop shortcut if one reg key is present.
I tried with the following:

```
$regPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\37efc56c15cbf10bt"
$shortcutPath = "c:\Users\Public\Desktop\notepad.lnk"
# Check if the registry key exists
if (Test-Path -Path $regPath) {
           Remove-Item -Path $shortcutPath -force
                    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I just add the dot. Yes, when I run the code, nothing happens. I tried in two computers and nothing happens. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make PowerShell recognize your path as a *registry* path, you have two options:

- Prepend `registry::`, i.e. a *[provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix*, to a *native* registry path:

  ```
  $regPath = 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\37efc56c15cbf10bt'
  ```
- Or - assuming that the native registry path has an equivalent PowerShell [drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Registry_Provider) - such as, in this case, `HKCU:` to refer to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry hive:

  ```
  $regPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\37efc56c15cbf10bt'
  ```

---

In the absence of either approach, a path such as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...` is interpreted as a *relative* path in the context of the provider underlying the [current location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations), which is typically a *file-system* location (i.e. one provided by the [`FileSystem` provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_FileSystem_Provider)).

By contrast, a path such as `c:\Users\Public\Desktop\notepad.lnk`, due to starting with a *drive specification*, is *unambiguous*, because the specified drive *implies* the underlying provider.

---

Separately, as you note yourself, it is better to use
`Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath('CommonDesktopDirectory')) notepad.lnk` to determine your `.lnk` file path based on the all-users desktop path instead of using hard-coded path `c:\Users\Public\Desktop\notepad.lnk`

Comment: Hi, thanks, change to HKCU:\ resolve the issue and use Environment]::GetFolderPath("CommonDesktopDirectory")to specify  user folder. Thanks again.